# Split screen video cliping with FFMpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

i have one video source with 4 different videos inside:
[image]

As you can see, i'm using VLC to view it and there is only one controlling window. If i press stop button, every 4 videos will stop and so on.

Problem is, i have to use FFMpeg and cut mini-clip from this source, so it will be playable in all 4 windows again. Clipping ordinary video works just fine with command `ffmpeg.exe -y -i $input -ss $startTime -t $length -acodec copy -vcodec copy $output 2>&1`. But when used for this one split-screen video, i get only one source clip instead of all 4 in same place.

**Any detailed information about this video is welcomed** because i don't even know how exactly this type of video is called, as well as any information about clipping with ffmpeg that video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found solution. It's video "container" with multiple streams. To copy streams, you have to use `-map` option between input and output parameters. So to cut out one clip of 10s using FFmpeg with multiple streams in video i use command `ffmpeg.exe -y -i $input -ss $startTime -t $length -map 0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy $output 2>&1`.